# monotouch/iOS: How to persentmodalview with transparent background

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, transparent

How to persentmodalview with transparent background, pls reference the following snapshot:

1. How to persent modal view with transparent( the image is png with transparent) - 
                but the background is still white (I have do this:set the alphal to 1.0 and viewcontroller.view.backgroundcolor to uicolor.clear)

   I used the uiviewcontroller.presentmodalviewcontroller to display the popwindow, not the addsubview. because there are many business logic in the viewcontroller)
2. When Users touch the area which outside the modalview, it can auto dismiss the modalview
                (just like the uipopover) 
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Opaque to false in all of the views involved, all the way to the white region.

Comment: if use the persentmodalviewcontrol, even the Opaque is set to false, it's still with the white region. Now I use the this.view.AddSubview,it's ok.